# How can I have multiple viewcontrollers in UIPageViewController display at once

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to have multiple viewControllers show in a single frame of a UIPageViewController. With the current page being centred in the UIPageViewController and the previous and next cards showing on the edge of the screen

I've been struggling to find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

[-> Like this <-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnlgV.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you are describing. A page view controller shows one page, or 2 pages with a spine in the middle. It has pages "waiting in the wings" for when the user flips/slides new pages, but I don't think it supports showing pages off the edge.

That said, it wouldn't be that hard to create your own parent/child view controller arrangement that does what you want. you might even be able to base it off of a UICollectionView.

Comment: You are right. I ended up using a UICollectionView. Thx!

Comment: Upvotes gratefully accepted (you have enough rep now!)